# Pandas DataFrame Not Saving To File

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning Python and can't seem to get pandas dataframes to save. I'm not getting any errors, the file just doesn't appear in the folder.

I'm using a windows10 machine, python3, jupyter notebook and saving to a local google drive folder.

Any ideas?

```
import feedparser
import pandas as pd

rawrss = [
    'http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_uk_edition/front_page/rss.xml',
    'https://www.yahoo.com/news/rss/',
    'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/feeds/index.xml',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch/',
    ]

posts = []
for url in rawrss:
    feed = feedparser.parse(url)
    for post in feed.entries:
        posts.append((post.title, post.link, post.summary))
df = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns=['title', 'link', 'summary']) # pass data to init

df.to_csv('df.to_csv('c:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\myfilename.csv', index=False)', index=False)
```

Comment: Did you try my answer by changing the file location? I ran your code and it's working fine!

Answer (score 2):

The file should be saved in the current working directory.

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code to the bottom of your file

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

That's where your file is

Try writing a simple file with a new script.

```
F = open(your_path_with_filename, 'w')
F.write("hello")
F.close()
```

Comment: The file isn't in that folder. It's not creating a new file

Comment: Ok. Any other exceptions being thrown? Try writing it to your User's Documents directory as a test. Remember to escape backslashes.

Comment: Tried this and got an error, I've updated the question to reflect the change and supplied the error.

Comment: Try escaping the backslashes. "Double backslash" \\

Comment: Sorry read/googled that bit after I made the update. No error message.

Comment: Make sure the data frame is valid with print(df) on the line above. Still no file?

Comment: It's still valid. And it's still not appearing.

Comment: See my updated answer. Does that work? Make sure to include your own path.

Comment: Still no result. I tried two different directories to be sure.

Comment: Ok, you have a filesystem permissions issue or your Python doesn't have access to the local filesystem. Only thing I can say at this point is try another machine.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of your code change this:

```
df.to_csv('C://myfilename.csv', index=False)
```

Now your file is saved in C drive.
You can change the path as per you wish.

for eg.

```
df.to_csv('C://Folder//myfilename.csv', index=False)
```

2.Alternatively ,If you want to locate where your file is stored.

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

This gives you the directory where the files are stored.
you can also change your working directory as per your wish.

Just at the beginning of your code

```
import os
os.chdir("path_to_folder")
```

In this case then no need of specifying path at the time of saving it to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that saves the file and returns a boolean value as the following:

```
import os
def save_data(path, file, df):
      if (df.to_csv(saving_path + file + '.csv', index = False)):
          return True
      else:
          return False
```

But you have to provide the right path though.