# How to Give Python Permission to Write Files

Tags: python, windows, windows-10

I'm learning Python and don't quite have the vocabulary to describe this. However, I can't seem to save files created in Python to my Window10 computer. I discovered this while seeking a help to try to get a [file to save in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796342/pandas-dataframe-not-saving-to-file/45796644#45796644). I then discovered the same problem when creating a db using SQLITE3 the script seemed to have fun but no database files appeared.

Does anyone know how to fix this? FYI I've got a dual boot Ubuntu machine, I can save files via Python in Ubuntu but really need it to work on my windows machine too.

I am running python via Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Could you post the exact code you are using in your notebook and the error message?

Comment: The code can be found in the link below, I didn't want to duplicate. I've ran this script while in my Ubuntu boot and it works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796342/pandas-dataframe-not-saving-to-file/45796644#45796644

Comment: If you didn't have access to the directory to create or modify files, then you would be getting an obvious `PermissionError` from Python. It wouldn't simply ignore the request.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a couple changes to the code snipped that you linked in order to get this to work.

A difference between windows and linux is the file path deliminator is a forward slash:

```
df.to_csv("tests/ysi_test_files/filehere.csv", index = False)
```

If you want a hard **absolute** path to a file, then do something like:

```
df.to_csv('C://Folder//myfilename.csv', index=False)
```

Again, if you copy the folder path from a windows folder you will get the backslashes instead of forward slashes.  You will need to change those in your code to save the file:

> C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\python\

to

> C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/python/

Comment: I just tested your suggestion, it still wouldn't save.

Comment: The Windows file API allows both forward slashes and backslashes. Also, forward slashes shouldn't be doubled in general because, for example, `//server//share/file.txt` is a UNC path that's not the same as the local path `/server/share/file.txt`. Only backslashes get doubled in order to escape them.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running the python script from command prompt then right click on it and run as administrator should solve the issue.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect this: I am running on Jupyter Notebook.